# Multiple PPT slides mearge into master PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to automate the creation of a presentation (Powerpoint.pptx). The presentation should take the first slide of each of the presentations(example I have 4 presentations and i will create one presentation out of 4) in a given directory, and then combine them into a single presentation. Then it will take 2nd slides of each presentation and insert them below the firstly pasted slides of master copy.
Input: 4 PPTs with different slides. But number of slides are same(13 here). Namely Name.pptx, Name_1.pptx,Name_2.pptx, Name_4.pptx.
Output: mearge 4 PPT's slide into one "Master PPT". but first PPT will be Name.pptx ans 2nd will be Name_1.pptx and so on.

Codes as below, but below code randomly selected PPTs from a group of 4 PPTs. PPT name is having no fixed format. How would i fixed any one as 1st PPT?

```
Sub PPTMerger()
Dim pp As PowerPoint.Application
Set pp = New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pres1 As PowerPoint.Presentation, pres2 As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pslide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim i As Long
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFolderName As String
strFolderName = "C:\Test\"
    pp.Presentations.Open ("C:\Test\Output\Master.pptx")
    For i = 2 To 13
        strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.pptx*")
        Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
           pp.Presentations.Open (strFolderName & "\" & strFileName)
           Set pres1 = pp.ActivePresentation
           pres1.Slides(i).Copy
           pp.Presentations.Item ("C:\Output\Master.pptx")
           pp.Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste
           pres1.Close
           strFileName = Dir
        Loop
        strFileName = "Nothing"
    Next
```

Comment: Hi - You may find it useful to take a look at this stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share your own attempts at a solution to enable people to advise/mentor/improve your own solution. A good place to start with VBA if you are a novice is to record your keystrokes using the record macro functionality, see what code is generated and use that as a starting point to build a solution

Comment: >>  "A good place to start with VBA if you are a novice is to record your keystrokes"  In Excel and Word, yes, but not PowerPoint. It has no macro recorder. Otherwise, excellent advice.

Comment: Goggling _PowerPoint VBA combine presentations_ will get you a useful starting point. When you get some code that sort of work, please update your question with it. The last version of PowerPoint with a macro recorder was 2003. I keep it installed just for that, sometimes it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you all for encouragement. I have develop a simple code one my own but facing few issues. Let me show you the codes:

Comment: @JohnnieL Could you please help me now?

Comment: @SuchisuvraBanerjee can you clarify "code randomly selected PPTs from a group of 4 PPTs." which 4?  "PPT name is having no fixed format." can you gibe an example? "How would i fixed any one as 1st PPT" - can you give a more precise spec?

Comment: @JohnnieL I have updated my comment above.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - thanks and wow, why I wonder? google tells me it was deprecated . Office 2010

Comment: @JohnnieL Apparently Google misuses "deprecated" in the same way MS does. To mean "We took it out back and shot it" rather than "We're advising customers not to use it any longer."  ;-)  IIRC, they sort of hid it in PPT 2007 then completely disabled it in 2010. Even though it had long been unable to record anything having to do with newer features and even some old ones and generally produced very low-quality code, it still had its uses, as JohnK's mentioned. I'd like to see them bring it back, even in its prior state.  Because, as JohnK's mentioned, it'd have its uses. ;-)

Comment: "We took it out back and shot it" - so true ... +1 from me to bring it back, simplest way to get eyes on the object model

Comment: @SuchisuvraBanerjee - I do not know much about vba in ppt but maybe check out the Slides object AddSlide method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide googling`site:learn.microsoft.com foo bar` is generally a clear and concise place to start